# `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node) on Vercel build, not on local

Tags: node.js, next.js, vercel, glibc

Node is set to 18 in Vercel project settings.
This is the error screen:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /vercel/path0/node_modules/bufferutil
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-gyp-build
npm ERR! node: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by node)
npm ERR! node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /vercel/.npm/_logs/2023-11-06T18_12_38_781Z-debug-0.log
Error: Command "npm install" exited with 1
```

The project builds without error locally on my Mac. but when I execute vercel in visual studio Code, I get the error on vercel.com.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same error today and resolved it by removing node from dependencies in package.json

You can do this by running:

```
npm uninstall node
```